# tcコマンドで送信速度を制限したい

Tags: centos, network

CentOS6 サーバにて、送信速度の制限を行いたいと思っています。

現在、IPアドレス 192.0.2.1 への送信速度を、次の方法で 1Mbps に制限しています。

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbps burst 1500
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.0.2.1 flowid 1:1
```

それに加えて、192.0.2.1 以外への送信速度を 500Kbps に制限したいのですが、どのようなコマンドで実現可能か教えて頂けますでしょうか。

試しに以下を実行してみましたが制限されませんでした。

```
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:2 htb rate 500kbps burst 1500
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst * flowid 1:2
```